# Redirect subfolder to another keeping query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

On Apache webserver, I would like to make a typed URL folder to match another, and convert the end of URL string to a query string for matched folder.

The typed URL can be:
`http://www.website.net/corp/view/folder1/folder2`

And the resulting viewed page would internally be:
`http://www.website.net/corp/files/?dir=folder1/folder2`

I tried the following rule in httpd.conf: 
`RewriteRule ^/corp/view/(.*) /corp/files/?dir=$1 [L]`, and I get a infinite loop, has the URL is self redirected...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.+` instead of `.*`:

```
RewriteRule ^/corp/view/(.+) /corp/files/?dir=$1 [L]
```

`.*` causes an infinite recursion as it also matches the empty string at the end of `/corp/files/`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it don't work. `.+` or `.*` have the same effect, and I just found what it happen: with F12 tools in IE9, I can see that `/corp/view/folder1` is redirected to `/corp/view/folder1/index.php/?dir=folder1`, to `/corp/view/folder1/index.php/index.php?dir=folder1/index.php`, and so on.

Comment: @Velcro: Oh sorry, I thought you were rewriting to the same directory. Well then, are there any other rules that could conflict with this one?

Comment: I have others rules, but no one with that pattern (I checked). BTW, I tried to put a [R] flag, and the redirection is ok. However, I would like to get an internal redirection aka URL-rewriting...

Comment: @Velcro: But I still guess that it’s another rule that is also applied.

Comment: @Gumbo: you were right. Thanks to RewriteLog, I discovered that it was my other rule which redirected unwanted queries (like invalid Host HTTP header) to a specific folder. I lost my day and your time, sorry...

Comment: **Hmmm** I was wrong... damned. All rules have been disabled with dashes, and still not working. Here is the rewrite log: http://paste2.org/p/1306498

Comment: Works: `RewriteRule ^/corp/view/(.*) /corp/dummy.php?dir=$1 [L]` - DONT works: `RewriteRule ^/corp/view/(.*) /corp/files/?dir=$1 [L]`